# Custom Animation With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do very basic, custom animation with JavaScript. I'm using a library called Modernizr to detect HTML5 support, and if a browser doesn't support CSS3 Transitions, I'd like to have my own custom (non jQuery) script that recreates the same effect of CSS3 Transitions.

My idea for this code is this:

JS:

```
function slide() {
  var cur = 0;
  while (cur <= 50) {
    setInterval("document.getElementById('slider').style.marginLeft=cur + 'px'",100);
    cur = cur++;
  }
}
```

HTML (for hovering):

```
<div id="slider" onmouseover="slide()">
  This should slide left.
</div>
```

This doesn't work (I know it doesn't loop, that's one of the issues that I can't figure out). I'm pretty new with JS so I don't know some pretty basic stuff.

The main reason that I don't want to use jQuery is for educational purposese. I want to know basic JS before I learn jQuery, just so I know how to do the things I want to do.

I'd like this to work for two different cases, one being automatically, one being only on hover (and the hover version doesn't have to loop). I had something kind of working on hover, but the more you hovered over it, the faster it would move.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function slide() {
  var cur = 0;
  while (cur >= 50) {
    setInterval("document.getElementById('slider').style.marginLeft=cur + 'px'",100);
    cur = cur++;
  }
}
```

Your code sets `cur` to `0`, and then the `while` condition is `cur >= 50` (*while `cur` variable is larger or equal to `50`) which will never be true because it is 0.

Also, animating with a loop is not a good idea, as the browser likely won't render the results in a manner that is pleasant to look at (or at all). Use `setInterval()` without the loop.

If I was tasked with writing this, it may look like...

```
function slide(element, newHeight) {
    var currentHeight = element.offsetHeight;
    var increaseHeight = function() {
        currentHeight += 10;
        element.style.height = currentHeight + 'px';
    }
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (currentHeight >= newHeight) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        increaseHeight();
    }, 100);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/yexGt/).

Comment: Ahh meant to use `<= 50`. but besides that, I still don't know how to do that setInterval() thing, mind giving me a quick example? ^^;

Comment: Took me a while to try this, sorry. That works perfectly. :) I tweaked it a bit for a smoother animation, http://jsfiddle.net/yexGt/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of doing sliding in javascript.

Here is one of them.

http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/06/how-to-create-an-animated-sliding-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/

In your example, if you use `setInterval` you will also want to call `clearInterval`.  For a description of both you can look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Hopefully you aren't actually using the `onmouseover` function in the element, as shown, but are instead checking if you need this, then setting it after the page has loaded.

You may want to look at unobtrusive javascript to get an idea how this can be done well.

There are various articles on this, but you could start with:

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/best_practices/separating_behavior.html